# Is it posible to use wild card to get list of directory in File::Find perl module?

Tags: perl, file-find

I want to list the directory path which contains the required directory.

For example:

```
                                 /usr1
                                    |
                                    |
                -----------------------------------------   
                |                                       |
            /local1                                     /local2
                |                                       |
              dir1                                      dir1
```

I want to find the directory path where dir1 is present using wild card `*`.

From linux command line I can do this to get the result.

```
find /usr1/local* -name dir1 -type d
```

then it will shows

```
/usr1/local1/dir1
/usr1/local2/dir1
```

The same way how can I do with File::Find perl module.

I don't want to use `system` or ``` `` ```  to get it done.

Comment: sorry for the structure.

Comment: Think you should read the documentation of the modul

Answer (score 7):

The equivalent of

```
find /usr1/local* ...
```

is

```
find(..., glob("/usr1/local*"))
```

so the whole is

```
use File::Basename qw( basename );
use File::Find     qw( find );

my $wanted = sub {
   say if basename($_) eq "dir1" && -d $_;
};

find({ wanted => $wanted, no_chdir => 1 }, glob("/usr1/local*"));
```

Personally, I prefer [File::Find::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Find::Rule).

```
use File::Find::Rule qw( );

say
   for
      File::Find::Rule
         ->name('dir1')
         ->directory
         ->in(glob("/usr1/local*"));
```

Comment: Won't `find` complain when `glob` returns files as well as directories?

Comment: @simbabque, No, neither `find` complains.

Comment: `find(..., grep{-d}glob("/usr1/local*"))`

Comment: @shawnhcorey, That would not be equivalent.